# cucumber using multiple example tables dynamically

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Is it possible to use different tables based on previous steps?

So suppose I have something like

```
When I choose from a <list> of things
And I run a <test> from that thing chosen with special <parameter>

Examples: 
   |list|
   | a |
   | b |

   | a |
   | test | parameter |
   | mytest1 | myparameter1 |
   | mytest2 | myparameter2 |

   | b |
   | test | parameter|
   | mytest1 | myparameter3 |
   | mytest2 | myparameter4 |
```

Is this possible and what would be the correct structure?

Answer (score 0):

No its not, and it is a very bad idea. Generally when you want to do programming in your scenarios, you should do it by

1. Giving it a name
2. Pushing the programming down into the step definitions

In this particular case you seem to want to be doing some sort of exhaustive testing, where you try a single operation under a number of different conditions. Cucumber is not appropriate for this sort of testing. Instead find a way to do these sort of tests at a lower level of abstraction e.g. a unit test.

The main reason for not doing exhaustive testing in Cucumber is the runtime cost. As a rough rule of thumb each integration test (Cucumber) has a run time cost of  hundreds of unit tests (maybe thousands of good unit tests).